# Can Nodejs validate a PHP user's session?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, websocket

**What am I working on?**

I am trying to establish a communication between a PHP app and a telephony system's REST API.

Since I my site is all written in PHP, I decided to build the communication using PHP by making cURL calls to the API.

to bring you up to speed, there are 2 types of communication between the user and the API and I like to put them into two different categories

- **Send Once / Receive Once** Example of this would, be a user attempt to dial a new phone number "dial 800-123-4567." The API takes the request and return back an interaction id to allow the user to control the call (i.e. disconnect, mute, put on hold.... )
- **Send Once / Receive Every Second** In this communication, I will create "persistent" connection between the user's session and the API. Then every second, I will check the API for new messages. After the message from the API is received, I must update the user's cache, read the latest user's cache, and finally send the browser the cache data.

**Problem?** HTTP is stateless.

Every request the user send to the web server, it generates a new TCP connection. The issue with this is that every second I query the API for new messages I will have a new TCP connection. On average about 200 TCP connections are needed at any giving time per user. So if I have 300 users using the app/server, then that is about 60,000 TCP connection open for the web server. As you can clearly see the solution does not scale well here and it is a matter of time before the server blow up in my face... :(

Another issue is that PHP is not asynchronous which cause problem if the communication to the API took longer or return errors.

FWIW, I have tried to user JavaScript SharedWorker to eliminate some of the overhead. I every tried Server-sent-events but a user still generated too many TCP connections to the server. nothing first the problem I was only able to reduce the connection a little.

**Can Nodejs help?**

I was advised by couple of people to use Nodejs instead of PHP for this task. Of course, I am not going to change my PHP application into Nodejs as this would be insane since my app is huge.

I would like to consider running a nodejs server as a middle man between the PHP server and the API service. The idea is to have a WebSocket running on the node server. Then, the client will pass any communication to the websocket and the websocket will then send the communication to the server. It does not sound bad at a high level but once a dig deeper, it seems to be getting trickier.

**Nodejs Challenge**

When a user logs into my PHP App, I validate their credentials and once they are in then I create a session which is stored into MySQL database. A session to be valid the following must be correct

- IP Address must match the Ip which created the session
- The agent data must also match (I can live without it for nodejs)
- The idle time of the session must be less that 900 seconds.

In order for Nodejs to start communication it must first create a new connection to the API. After the connection is accepted, nodejs must keep track of the following data "received by the API"

1. CSFR token
2. Session Id
3. Http Cookie

In order for Nodejs to make a connection to the API it must pass a username, password, server name, port, and a station name. I have all the needed info stored into MySQL database and I can easily get that using PHP.

The challenge is that NodeJS have to take the PHP session, validates it, pull the API needed info from the database then establish connection to the API.

**Questions**

Can nodejs use the PHP session to validate the user? If so how?

How will can nodejs use the TCP connection to prevent me from overloading the server?

Comment: Off-topic, but I wonder if a message queue would help you alleviate the scalability problem?

Comment: Also off topic, but why not kill the TCP connections when they're done, if you're not reusing them? Or better, find a way to keep the connection alive and _have the client reuse it_ instead of making a new one?

Comment: @Ghedipunk I tried to add "Connection: Close" in my request but my windows server seeks in in a Wait_time for 60 seconds I don't know if I can control what tcp connection to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is your arrangement:

```
[User browser]  ->  [PHP]  ->  [Node.js]  ->  [API]
```

When your user's browser sends a request to your PHP server the request includes a cookie - one of the values of this cookie is the `session id` which PHP then uses to look up the session. The `session id` acts like a password, PHP will assume that if you've got the session id then you are the original user that was issued that id.

When your PHP script communicates with Node it needs to pass along that session id as part of the request. In Node you just then need to do a lookup of your sessions table in MySQL for the corresponding session.

PHP session data is stored as the `$_SESSION` array serialised. To extract data from it you will need to unserialise it first. There are a number of libraries out that can provide this functionality (e.g. https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize, https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/var/unserialize.js). However if the session data is simple and conforms to a known format you could 'hand parse' the data.

Comment: thank you for your help. This makes since. Now will nodejs query the session table on every page load? I don't want to keep calling the session table so I would like to do it once per user. Additionally, how would I keep track with my `CSFR token`, `Session Id`, and `Http Cookie` after the session API login? do I need to have a websocket server and then a node.js server running at the same time?

Comment: `will nodejs query the session table on every page load` depends completely on how you write your node.js code! As for the other variables it sounds like you need to maintain a session in nodejs, but I think it's best you open another question about that.

Comment: I am little confused. so does this mean I still need a websocket to communicate between the web browser and the node.js application who will be making call to the API and keeping track of the user's session?